# How to allow only authorised clients to access object properties

Tags: php

Some of my PHP domain objects have properties which should be set from outside the object, but only by certain client objects. How can I go about enforcing this?

I am using setters within the class, and provided I can find a way to discriminate between different callers, I'm sure I could do some checking in the setter.  This seems a bit convoluted though.  I get the feeling that I'd be violating an OO design principle (perhaps "tell, don't ask"?).

I imagine this is a reasonably common scenario.  What am I missing?

Comment: I think a good ACL will help me here too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It strikes me as a bad design in this case. You'd violate the single-responsibility principle of the class. Instead, refactor your code into more than one class, but use composition to attach optional properties.

For example:

```
class MyDataObject {
    private $main_property;
    private $extended_property;

    /* ... getters/setters for $main_property. */
    public function set_extended_property(IExtendedProperty $property) {
        $this->extended_property = $property;
    }
}
```

Where `IExtendedProperty` is an interface for the custom property data.

Comment: Hi Joshua, not sure what you mean.  Here you are using a setter within the main class, which is what I'm currently doing.  You're not discriminating between callers either.  Any client could call your setter...

Comment: Discriminating between callers is the problem: your classes shouldn't have any insight into what is calling their methods. Instead of  trying to filter and control method calls, have the caller create a new instance of the object with the custom properties or have it inject the custom data into the instance of the class (like the code above).